How test a file drag-and-drop using Vitest?
I'm trying to test a drag-and-drop of a file into a Vue component and right now I'm using Vitest but all the resources on drag-and-drop I found were only for using Jest to achieve that so:
How to test a file drag-and-drop using Vitest?

it('render properly Drivers Drag and drop', async () => {
    mockAll(webWorker)
    const wrapper = mount(LoadsTabs, {
        global: {
            plugins: [VueQueryPlugin],
            components: {
                LoadsTabs,
                CustomerReport
            },
        }
    });
    await flushPromises()
    await awatiTime()
    const driver = wrapper.findComponent(Driver)
    expect(driver.exists()).toBeTruthy()
    await driver.trigger('dragstart')
    const tableItem = wrapper.findComponent(TableItem)
    expect(tableItem.exists()).toBeTruthy()
    await tableItem.trigger('drop')
    await flushPromises()
    expect(webWorker.lastRequest?.path).toContain('/charge/update/')
    expect(webWorker.lastRequest?.path).toContain('/assign')
    expect(webWorker.lastRequest?.method).toContain('PATCH')
})

You can try this. I had the same problem and it works for me.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
